# Codeigniter, How to store value from query inside foreach

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a code like this

```
$this->load->model("m_crud");
$test= $this->m_crud->get_querry; //this model already have query and result() to return
foreach($test as $retest)
   {
    echo $retest->primary_id;
    $test2=$this->db->query("select * from table2 where id='$retest");
    foreach($test2 as $retest2)
       {
         echo $retest2->name;
        }
   }
```

Its easy to just put all this code to "**views**" but I want to use MCV model.
I tried to store the result using array like this:

```
$data['test']=$test
foreach($test as $retest)
   {
    echo $retest->primary_id;
    $test2=$this->db->query("select * from table2 where id='$retest");
    $data['test2']=$test2
    foreach($test2 as $retest2)
       {
         echo $retest2->name;
        }
   }
$this->load->view("test_view",$data);
```

What I got in the view is I have the same value from the echo of `$test2`, which should be differently by each of `$test`

thank you, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

It is easy here is an example

Controller Method

```
function getResult()
{
    $this->load->model('mymodel');
    $results    =   $this->mymodel->getRecords();
    $data['results']    =   $results;
    $this->load->view('myview',$data);
}
```

Model Method

```
function getRecords()
{
    return $this->db->query("select * from table2 where id='$retest")->result_array();
}
```

And view

```
foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $row['othercolumn'];
}
```

Comment: sorry, but that's not the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  in view page

```
foreach($test2 as $newarray)
{
     foreach($newarray->result() as $row)
     {
           echo $row->columnnames;//
     }
}
```